# Heatmap of a matrix of zeros and ones using image function in R

Tags: r, heatmap

how can i make a black and white heatmap of a given matrix that consists of zeros and ones where the zeros are depicted with black and the ones with white using the image function in r?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a matrix:

```r
set.seed(42)
mat <- matrix(round(runif(100)), ncol = 10)
mat
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#>  [1,]    1    0    1    1    0    0    1    0    1     1
#>  [2,]    1    1    0    1    0    0    1    0    0     0
#>  [3,]    0    1    1    0    0    0    1    0    0     0
#>  [4,]    1    0    1    1    1    1    1    0    1     1
#>  [5,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    1     1
#>  [6,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    0    1    1     1
#>  [7,]    1    1    0    0    1    1    0    0    0     0
#>  [8,]    0    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    0     1
#>  [9,]    1    0    0    1    1    0    1    1    0     1
#> [10,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    0    0    0     1
```

Plot it:

```r
image(t(mat[nrow(mat):1,]), col = c("black", "white"))
```

`t()` and `nrow(mat):1` are used to reorder the matrix so the image of the matrix matches up with the printed matrix.

[image]